# cross-env NODE_ENV=development API_ENV=development PERMISSIONS=disabled node server

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

Hi when i try to npm run start, it is showing the error :cross-env NODE_ENV=development API_ENV=development PERMISSIONS=disabled node server

Comment: The message does not look like an error. Are you sure there isn't more to it?

Comment: I think iam using latest version of Node and npm, but my ongoing project node version is older,

Comment: if i install olderversion of node, can i solve the problem with it?

Comment: Sure, a re-install may help., hopefully. If that did not work, it would be worth considering showing the whole error message.